# Jesus grew in favour with God

Tags: jesus, luke

There are many similar questions, but do not ask the specific question as below.  This is mainly from the Trinitarian perspective, but happy for all to respond.

If Jesus is God, how can he grow **in more favour with God,** even if the father sent his son in the flesh, how could he increase his favour to his son who he sent & who is part of the Godhead?

Berean Literal Bible

Luke 2:52

> And Jesus continued to advance in wisdom and stature, and **in favor with God** and men.

Luke 2:40

> And the Child continued to grow and become strong, being filled with wisdom. And the **grace of God** was upon Him.

Acts 7:10

> and rescued him out of all his tribulations, and gave **him favor** and wisdom before Pharaoh king of Egypt, and he appointed him ruler over Egypt and over all his house.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate : [How did Jesus grow in favour with God ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76030/how-did-jesus-grow-in-favour-with-god-luke-252).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is specifically addressed by the Apostle Paul using the (now) technical word, "kenosis".

> Phil 2:5-8 - have the same mindset as Christ Jesus: Who, being in very
> nature a God, did not consider equality with God something to be used
> to his own advantage; rather, he made himself nothing [= κενόω]
>
> - by taking the very nature of a servant,
> - being made in human likeness.
> - And being found in appearance as a man,
> - he humbled himself
> - by becoming obedient to death—
> - even death on a cross!

Thus, Paul simply says that Jesus was God but voluntarily humbled Himself to become human; that is, He clothed Himself with humanity so that we "*beheld His glory, a glory as of the One and only from the Father, full of grace and truth.*" (John 1:14)

Thus, Luke 2:40, 52 describe Jesus' humanity and His example to us (Eph 5:2, 1 John 2:6, etc).  Ellicott comments on V40:

> **Filled with wisdom**.—The Greek participle implies the continuous
> process of “being filled,” and so conveys the thought expressed in
> Luke 2:52, of an increase of wisdom. The soul of Jesus was human,
> i.e., subject to the conditions and limitations of human knowledge,
> and learnt as others learn. The heresy of Apollinarius, who
> constructed a theory of the Incarnation on the assumption that the
> Divine Word (the Logos of St. John’s Gospel) took, in our Lord’s
> humanity, the place of the human mind or intellect, is thus, as it
> were, anticipated and condemned.

Ellicott then goes to comment on V52:

> **In favour with God and man**.—This, it will be noted, is an addition to what had been stated in Luke 2:40, and gives the effect while that
> gave the cause. The boy grew into youth, and the young man into
> manhood, and the purity and lowliness and unselfish sympathy drew even
> then the hearts of all men. In that highest instance, as in all lower
> analogies, men admired holiness till it became aggressive, and then it
> roused them to an antagonism bitter in proportion to their previous
> admiration.

The author of Hebrews expresses it this way:

> Heb 5:7-9 - During the days of Jesus’ earthly life, He offered up
> prayers and petitions with loud cries and tears to the One who could
> save Him from death, and He was heard because of His reverence.
> Although He was a Son, He learned obedience from what He suffered. And
> having been made perfect, He became the source of eternal salvation to
> all who obey Him

**APPENDIX - Kenosis [lit: becoming nothing"] of Jesus**

The Bible presents a simple sequence to demonstrate the eternal pre-existence of Jesus:

- Jesus existed with God in heaven and was instrumental in the creation
- Jesus became human (was incarnated)
- Jesus died and was resurrected and returned to heaven.

We see this many times in the Bible, especially in the Gospel of John, such as:

- John 1:1-3 - In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was with God in the beginning. Through Him all things were made, and without Him nothing was made that has been made.
- John 1:14 - The Word became flesh and made His dwelling among us. We have seen His glory, the glory of the one and only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth.
- John 1:15 - John testified concerning Him. He cried out, saying, “This is He of whom I said, ‘He who comes after me has surpassed me because He was before me.’ ”
  •   John 1:18 - No one has ever seen God, but the one and only Son, who is Himself God and is at the Father’s side, has made Him known.
- John 3:13 - No one has ascended into heaven except the One who descended from heaven—the Son of Man.
- John 3:16, 17 - For God so loved the world that He gave His one and only Son, that everyone who believes in Him shall not perish but have eternal life. For God did not send His Son into the world to condemn the world, but to save the world through Him. [NOTE - God cannot send someone who does not exist!]
- John 3:31 - The One [= Jesus] who comes from above is above all. The one who is from the earth belongs to the earth and speaks as one from the earth. The One who comes from heaven is above all.
- John 6:38 - For I have come down from heaven, not to do My own will, but to do the will of Him who sent Me.
- John 6:46 - not that anyone has seen the Father except the One who is from God; only He has seen the Father.
- John 6:61, 62 - But Jesus, aware that his disciples were complaining about this, said to them, “Is this offensive to you? What then if you see the son of man ascending to where he was before?
- John 8:38 - I speak of what I have seen in the presence of the Father
- John 8:58 - “Truly, truly, I tell you,” Jesus declared, “before Abraham was [born], I am!”
- John 13:1, 3 - It was now just before the Passover Feast, and Jesus knew that His hour had come to leave this world and return to the Father. Having loved His own who were in the world, He loved them to the very end. ... Jesus knew that the Father had delivered all things into His hands, and that He had come from God and was returning to God.
- John 16:27, 28 - for the Father himself loves you, because you have loved me and have believed that I came from God.  I came from the Father and have come into the world, and now I am leaving the world and going to the Father.”
- John 17:5 - And now, Father, glorify Me in Your presence with the glory I had with You before the world existed.  See also V24.
- Phil 2:5-11 – “*Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus: Who, existing in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness. And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient to death— even death on a cross*”.  Jesus then returns to heaven in the next few verses:
- Phil 2:9-11 - Therefore God exalted Him to the highest place and gave Him the name above all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

Comment: Excellent presentation +1

Comment: @ Dottard an argument for Trinity (albeit IMO a lot of holes), doesn't answer the Q - even if Jesus was human, flesh, weak, humbled, etc etc... God the father who sent him loved him more after making him human, even though J is God & part of the Godhead?  I note you mention not equal, so F is a higher God then J so J needs to seek his honour / pleasure?

Comment: @anothertheory - actually, my answer does not mention the trinity, nor is it a defense of the trinity.  This is an attempt to answer the question as posed - Jesus was God but voluntarily humbled Himself to become human. after which he was again exalted.

Comment: @Dottard - indirectly you do seem to, F & J are God.  ‘Exalted’ IMO doesn’t really help you, Jesus was exalted even after his resurrection, Not just back to God with all his (God) glory, God J still needs to be ‘exalted' by another supreme God.  Anyway, noted with thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is found in how the bible describes who Jesus is and how he gets his work of salvation done here on earth.  The doctrine/teaching that describes this is Jesus' *State of Humiliation/exinanition.*  Jesus, in his state of exinanition, for the most part, gives up the *use* of his divine attributes.  He does not give up the *possession* of his divine attributes. Jesus, from eternity, to eternity, is God. But *so that he can suffer and save*, Jesus often gives up the *use* of these attributes. In my notes for this bible passage, I have the following:

> II.   In the exinanition Christ voluntarily gave up the full use of His
> divine prerogatives for a time.
>
> 1. Negatively, He emptied Himself of the ἴσα εἶναι θεῷ.  cf  Jn 17:5; Mt 8:20; 2 Cor 8:9; Ps 110:1; Eph 1:20; Lk 22:42,54; Mk 11:13;
>    Mt 24:36; Jn 11:34; Is 7:15; Lk 2:52; Mt 21:19.
>
> a)  He did not give up any of the divine attributes.        cf  Kenoticism.
> cf  κτῆσις (possession) and κρῆσις. (use)
>
> b)   Temporarily giving up the full use of the divine attributes is
> sometimes called concealment.         1)  There was a secret use.             cf  Jn
> 5:17; 3:13; 1:18.         2)  This was not identical with the sessio ad
> dextram.      3)  Even now there is a certain concealment.            cf  He 2:8; 1
> Cor 1:7 (Gr.). (Deus Absconditus:  Even in his state of exaltation he
> still is concealed)
>
> c)  Careful moderation is in place: the divine mystery is to be
> adored, it cannot be explained.

The simplest example of this is Jesus' mode of transportation. Jesus as true God is omnipresent and omnipotent.  Yet, when he goes from Nazareth to Jerusalem, he walks.

A more difficult, yet important example of this is Jesus' knowledge.  How is it that Jesus can be surprised at the Centurion's faith or not know the day/time of his own return on Judgment Day? (Mark 13:32)

A proper answer is not found by saying, "Jesus was also a human." For the Divine Nature shares its attributes with the human nature at Jesus' conception. Instead, the proper understanding is found here in how Jesus gets his work of salvation done here on this earth: He humbles himself both to keep the law in our place and to be able to suffer in our place.

Comment: Another good example is "When thou wast under the fig tree I saw thee." +1

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of this passage has to do with Christ's having both a [fully human and fully divine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union) nature. Insofar as a person is made up of a human (physical) and spiritual (immaterial soul) 'nature', so too was Jesus. However, unlike our own, His spiritual nature is the second person of the Trinity, which is fully divine. There are many statements of Jesus' divinity in the gospels (ex: [John 8:58](https://biblehub.com/john/8-58.htm)). However, he is also confirmed to be fully human in Hebrews 2:14-15:

> Because God's children are human beings -- made of flesh and blood -- the Son also became flesh and blood. For only as a human being could he die, and only by dying could he break the power of the devil, who had the power of death. Only in this way could he set free all who have lived their lives as slaves to the fear of dying. (NLT)

In order for Christ's death to be capable of atoning for humanity's sins He must have been fully human in order to take upon Himself the punishment for human sins, and He also must have been fully divine in order to account for the practically infinite magnitude of those sins.

Under this view of Christ's dual nature, it is expected that his human nature would be imperfect, and therefore that it would grow in maturity throughout his life in a similar way that any other person might, including in His relationship to God the Father.

In answer to OP's comment under @Dottard 's answer, I do not believe "grew in favor with God" from the verse refers to an increase in God's love for Jesus, as God has an infinite and unconditional love for all people by default, including the incarnate Christ. Rather I would take this to describe an increase in the relationship between God the Father and Jesus in His human nature as Jesus matured throughout his life from, for example, a child's understanding of God the Father to an adult's. Similarly, while Jesus did not sin, all sinners (but not their sinful actions) are loved infinitely and unconditionally by God, but the worse sinner is certainly less favored.

---

A good resource for this question and the doctrine of the incarnation is [Reasonable Faith: Doctrine of Christ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvb7IoEv5oc&list=PLIpO3BUiq2IHGVH6rDrtI5O6F6I-aw5ff&ab_channel=ReasonableFaithOrg) introducing and examining the topic by William Lane Craig. I believe I remember this exact verse, and others like it, being covered in detail.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

The simple and straightforward answer to this question is this: Jesus, as **a man** grew in favor of God. In fact, as a man, Jesus was in need of more favor from God because as the blameless (without blemish and spot- 1 Pet 1:19) Lamb of God, He was not to commit even a single sin. One sin and He is no Savior of the world.

**Explanation**

It is a human tendency on the believers’ part to interpret the Scripture to suit the human “theories” formulated by the early church fathers or late medieval church founders. And most of them were heavily influenced by or sympathetic to Greek philosophy.

One such theory was about the nature of the incarnate Word; whether He was only a man or God or both; whether His divine nature was dormant or concealed within His human nature; whether at His death, His divine nature survived Him etc.

But the Scripture is very plain:

God didn’t do any gimmicks or concealment. No false pretensions.

Jesus, as the Word of God existed as God prior to His incarnation (Philip 2:6). The Word (Jesus) was God and was with God (John 1:1). In fact, He was the very Yahweh who interacted with Israel and was seen and heard by them in the Old Testament (Heb 11:26). But at one time in history, the Word “emptied Himself” and became fully a man (Philip 2:7).

What did the Word empty Himself of?

Yes, He emptied Himself of His divine attributes so that when He became a man, He was fully a man, just as any man. When He was fully a man, He did not have any divine power or attributes.

The personality and character of Jesus was 100% God while on earth but without any divine attributes or power. The Person was the same yesterday, today and forever. But during a short period, while on earth, the same God became man and had only human attributes.

Of course, Jesus knew who He was. Hence He showed authority over many things with the help of God the Father.

But there was no concealment of any divine attributes because He left all of that with God His Father. He “emptied Himself” of the divine glory and attributes. That is why He prayed:

> “And now Father, glorify Me with Yourself, with the **glory which I
> HAD** with You before the existence of the world” (John 17:5).

Jesus didn’t pray to remove any concealment but to give back the divine glory which He had with the Father. He left this glory with the Father when He emptied Himself.

There was no concealment or dormancy of His glory in His human nature.

This is why Jesus got tired (John 4:6). (He didn’t pretend to be tired). He felt hungry (Matt 4:2; 21:18; Mark 11:12), thirsty (John 4:7), sleepy (Matt 8:24) etc. These all were real and genuine human feelings; not pretensions. He was mortal (hence He died) and flesh and blood. Anybody could kill Him and the Romans did it.

While on earth as human, Jesus was not omniscient (Mar 13:32). He depended fully (100%) on God His Father as an obedient second Adam.

He Himself testifies:

> “I **can do nothing on my own** authority; I judge only as God tells
> me, so my judgment is right, because I am not trying to do what I
> want, but only what he who sent me wants” (John 5:30).

(It is funny that when Jesus testifies that He can do nothing on His own, people say, no, no, You can do but You are not utilizing Your concealed divine attributes).

> Christ Jesus “who in the days of His flesh was offering both petitions
> and entreaties to Him being able to **save Him from death**, with
> **strong crying and tears**, and being heard from His **godly fear**; though being a Son, He **learned obedience** from what He suffered and
> having been **perfected**” (Heb 5:7-9).

I have often heard people, especially Unitarians and others from one other religion, asking how God can have blood, how God can die etc. Well, the Scripture shows how; through the Incarnation. God as God cannot die but God became man and died, in history. God as God cannot have blood but God became man and shed His blood for the sin of the humanity, in history.

Others ask how God can empty Himself. But who else can empty himself? Can a human empty himself? Can an animal empty itself? No.

So, this is how Jesus grew in more favor with God. Sifted out from philosophy, this, to me, is the truth as shown plainly in Scripture.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on perspectives you take on the Lord Jesus Christ. In a correct Chalcedonian Christology Christ has only one personality, the hypostacity, that of the Logos who was always with the Father eternally born from the Latter, through whom and by whom the universe, the entire created order of reality was created, Himself Logos being thus uncreated. Now, this Person of Logos adopted/assumed human nature from the Virgin Mary, and since then the Logos is always considered together with this assumed/adopted human nature, which He made His own eternally, so one can now pray to Logos (like, "O, Word of God, save me!") and to Christ ("Christ, save me!") being sure that the very same Person is addressed.

Thus, when the Lord was born, the same Person who sucked Mary's breast also simultaneously held the entire universe to existence alongside with the Father and the H. Ghost, for to keep something into existence is the same as to give this something existence, for exertion of exactly the same energy is needed for both, as Descartes brilliantly showed in his 3rd metaphysical meditation.

Now how did he "grew in favour with God"? This is a perspective of His humanity, for He possessed human intelligent soul, which grew like His body grew; through this human intelligent soul He was humanly obedient to parents, humanly was gladdened by intimacy with His family members, Mother and the adopted father Joseph and Joseph's other children from his first wife; learned things; played games but never cheated in them; was growing as a good and parent abiding kid both in His human body and in His human intelligent soul, for both are aspects of human nature adopted by Him. Thus, as about a good, parent-abiding and virtue-practicing kid it could be said that "he grows in favor of God", so the kid Jesus prospered perfectly in those human categories as being fully human, through his human body and human intelligent soul.

However, He cannot grow or develop in His divine essence, *qua* Perfect Logos, co-Perfect with His Father (cf. Hebrews 7:28), for if you know your knower as your knower knows you, then you are equal to your knower and your knower is equal to you, and this is true with the Father and the Son (John 10:15; Matthew 11:27).

Answer (score 0):

If Jesus is God, how can he grew in more favor with God?

If Jesus is God, then there will be 2 Gods. Jesus and his God does not count as 1 because according to Jesus he and His God count as two, John 8:17-18.

John 8:17-18 Literal Standard Version

and also in your law it has been written that the testimony of two men is true I am [One] who is testifying of Myself, and the Father who sent Me testifies of Me.

If Jesus is God, then Luke 2;52 does not make sense. God is not born and then grows. If, as others say, that Jesus is 100% God and 100% man, then Jesus does not need to grow. God is not incomplete that He needs to grow. If Jesus grew in wisdom, if there were things that he had to learn and things that he did not know, then his divine nature was not the highest. Jesus is the son of the Most High God. The most High God does not need to grow, thus, Jesus is not the most High God.  He is not equal to God. John 14:28.

If Jesus is God, was he masquerading as a newborn infant after he was born? Was the 100% God/man circumsized?

Jesus' own admission shows he is ignorant of the day and of the hour of his return  and he said that only his Father knows the day of his return, that excludes the holy spirit too. If Jesus said that in his capacity as a man, why is the holy spirit excluded from knowing Jesus' return?

If Jesus is God and man, how can one explain God being born? is being born also the same as being incarnated?

Others claim that Jesus is God but emptied (kenoo) himself, using Phil. 2:6. What is there left in Jesus if he emptied himself? Is Jesus then an empty God? Is he still God if he is empty? If Jesus did not regard being equal with God as a thing to be coveted or seized, where Paul was teaching the Philippian believers to be humble, how is this verse an example of humility that Jesus did not think it robbery to be equal with God?

If Jesus is God, is it not absurd to say that Jesus thought it not robbery to be equal to himself?

To answer this question and state that Jesus was both God and man is self-contradictory. God is not born, Jesus was. Jesus was circumcised. Was God circumcised when Jesus was circumcised?  Did God die when Jesus died?.

Those who delusively use Philippians 2:6 are imposing on Jesus what he did not consider, that is seizing, and thus, conveying the opposite meaning of Philippians 2:6.

Answer (score -1):

it's simple is trinity is fake and stupid. Please research carefully, we can not explain bible by us but only bible's words.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).